# SQL to evaluate a condition only certain cases db2 and sybase

Tags: sql, db2, sybase

I need a certain where clause in my query to be evaluated only in some conditions.

For example,

```
select * from employee e where e.age=14 and e.salary=1000
```

In the above query I need salary where clause to be evaluated only when `e.age > 30`

I am using Db2 and sybase.

Comment: `select * from employee e where e.age=14 and e.salary=1000 and e.age >30;`

Answer (score 0):

Use `OR` if you want to add conditions to your query that shouldn't apply always, like this:

```
SELECT *
FROM employee e
WHERE e.age = 14 OR (e.age>30 AND e.salary=1000)
```

This will give you all results for `e.age = 14` no matter what the salary AND all results for `e.age>30` where the salary is 1000.

Comment: Not really , here is what is needed

Answer (score 0):

Do this

```
    Select * from employee e where e.age=14 or e.age>30 and e.salary=1000
```

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
select * 
from   employee e
where  e.age = 14 -- change to any age you want, then ...

and   (-- if age > 30 then we also need to check salary
       (e.age >  30 and e.salary = 1000)
       or
       -- if age <= 30 then we don't care about salary
       (e.age <= 30)
      )
```

The key is to have complementary `where` clauses (`e.age > 30` or `e.age <= 30`) that cover all rows in the table.

---

Another possibility (should work in Sybase ASE, don't know about DB2 syntax) ...

```
select * 
from   employee e
where  e.age = 14 -- change to any age you want, then ...

and    e.salary = case when e.age > 30 
                       then 1000      -- when e.age >  30, e.salary=1000
                       else e.salary  -- when e.age <= 30, e.salary=e.salary
                  end
```